# Inspect element to view js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-inspector

At example.noodles.com is a server running a node.js application. Is there a way that I could view the source files of that application using inspect element or anything else?

So far all I can view is the html which is not useful to me and the files do not appear in the resources section.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Nope. Server-side files are server-side.

Comment: Unless you're debugging your own application and use something like `node inspector` (of which that would mean you would already have the source code anyways), no you definitely cannot view server side files that you don't own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NodeJS is a platform for server side javascript programming. Like other server side languages (java for example) the server side code resides only in the server (it only computes based on inputs, if any, and returns the output). The server side code is not available on the client side. 
The inspect element feature inspects only the client side resources/files etc. (that are available when you for example access a webpage).
The server side javascript is never downloaded. Thats why you cant access them in the resources section.
If it still confuses you, try and relate it to a java based server client architecture. only instead of Java you have javascript and instead of JRE, you have Google's V8 javascript engine.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Watch this video
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03qGA-GJXjI

Here are a few Libraries which can give you the following features:

- https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector
- https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Debugging-with-devtools
- https://greenido.wordpress.com/2013/08/27/debug-nodejs-like-a-pro/
- Navigate in your source files
- Set breakpoints (and specify trigger conditions)
- Step over, step in, step out, resume (continue)
- Inspect scopes, variables, object properties
- Hover your mouse over an expression in your source to display its value -- in a tooltip
- Edit variables and object properties
- Continue to location
- Break on exceptions
- Disable/enable all breakpoints
- Node Inspector uses WebSockets, so no polling for breaks.
- Remote debugging
- Live edit of running code, optionally persisting changes back to the file-system.